# java 8 lambda Optional.ofNullable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

My method returns:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(solution)
            .map(Solution::getPrice)
            .map(solutionPrice-> BuildPayment(solutionPrice, name))
            .orElse(Mono.just(Price.Builder.create().build()))
            .map(price-> buildProcessResponse(solution, price));
```

My method fails when solution is null. when I debug it seems that when solution is null the method go to orElse and enter the final map.

How should I init "solution" if it is null?

Comment: *it seems that when solution is null the method go to orElse and enter the final map* - this is exactly what should happen in the presented code. What do you actually want to achieve? What should happen if `solution` is `null`?

Comment: Why are you mixing optional and mono?

Comment: `Mono.justOrEmpty(solution).map(...).map(...).or(Mono.just(...)).map(...)`

Comment: @lexicore if solution null, I want to call buildProcessResponse with new Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it's hard to figure out what's the final purpose of your code. In order to create a new solution when it's null, the following snippet could help:

```
    return Optional.ofNullable(solution)
            .orElseGet(Solution::new)
            .map(solution -> buildProcessResponse(solution, solution.getPrice()));
```